# TCA Frontend User by User Group Click Show

Tags: typo3

Hello I am now writing a TYPO3 extension and in the Backend Module of the Extension I want to go to Access and then I want to click on the groups and on the left side then there i want to have the users of the Group.
I think it will be possible to configure this with TCA but I have no idea how.
Have already tried everything but I have no idea.

```
/*TCA KONFIGURATION NOW */
'fe_group' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.fe_group',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
        'size' => 5,
        'maxitems' => 20,
        'items' => [
            [
                'LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.hide_at_login',
                -1,
            ],
            [
                'LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.any_login',
                -2,
            ],
            [
                'LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.usergroups',

            ],
        ],
        'exclusiveKeys' => '-1,-2,',
        'foreign_table' => 'fe_groups',
        'foreign_table_where' => 'ORDER BY fe_groups.title',
    ],
],
```

Comment: I think we need to clarify a few phrases. what do you mean with `Backend Module`? and which `Access`? where should the users be seen?

Comment: Ok i am now writing an extension with typo3 and when i go into the List Module in the Backend i go to a folder and select my Extension then have 3 Panels on the top and one is Access. There i can set the start-date and end-date and the usergroup for this new news but i want that when i select the User group on the Right side that on the left side all users of this group will be there thank  you

Comment: just verifying I understand it: if you select `your extension` in the list module: do you have records of your own type or do you use a plugin as a content record?

Comment: I have record of my own type

Comment: as the usergroup-selection is a TYPO3 build in function for regulating access to records. I assume that is the function you want. but you also want to show the editor, which users are covered with that selection. this can be done with a [`fieldwizard`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Check.html#fieldwizard)

Comment: Thank you do you have any example for my reason ?

Comment: sorry, I have not done anything with fieldwizards